# Client-side vs server-side database transactions

Tags: sql-server, transactions

In `SQL Server` transactions can either be performed in client or server code. A database expert once told me that client-side transactions should be avoided due to locking issues. Now, several years later, I want to know if that still holds true.

Certainly, there are scenarios where client-side transactions are necessary, but let's assume that a specific problem can be solved using either client or server side transactions.

**In terms of performance, which of the two techniques is best? Why?**

**C# (client):**

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Insert data into database.

    transaction.Complete();
}
```

**T-SQL (server):**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_proc]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TransactionCount [int]

    BEGIN TRY
        SET @TransactionCount = @@TRANCOUNT

        IF @TransactionCount = 0
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

        -- Insert data

        IF @TransactionCount = 0
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 AND @TransactionCount = 0 
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

        ; THROW
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Server side transaction are more efficient. Think of it this way. If you start a transaction client-side then the server has to know that a transaction is in progress in order to commit or rollback. This also results in more communication between the client application and the database server.

Answer (score 2):

I am a massive advocate of client side transactions, so long as they're done correctly.

When you're performing a client side transaction, all you are really doing is opening a connection and sending 'BEGIN TRAN'. From here, when you pass the transaction object around your different classes and perform updates, you are simply using that open connection. I don't fully agree with Gregg's answer for this reason, because you're using an open connection with an open transaction, so the server will always 'know'.

Assuming it is correctly surrounded in a Try/Finally to close it and also a 'using' block they are pretty concrete. After 10 years of successfully using them I have never had locking issues.

I commonly use a framework that contains multiple child classes inside it ... for example, think a 'customer' object with a collection of telephone numbers and addresses inside it, each with their own update routines for each item.

If i were to perform an update on the parent, it would be very hard to rollback the changes using server side transactions as the updates are all neatly ordered into their own update sprocs for each table/entity.

Passing around a client side transaction and calling the stored procedures inside this transaction gives me the option to cleanly rollback when any exception is thrown and commit once we know the update has completed.

Client side Transactions are a gift from the big man himself when you use them correctly.